# Google OAuth: Log My User Out When They Sign Out of Google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, google-oauth

I have a Rails app that uses Devise with the [Google OAuth gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) to get Google users to accredit themselves for my app.

My understanding of OAuth is that we take the word of a trusted site (Google) that a user is who they say they are: after that, the fact that the user is logged into their Google account should be irrelevant to our site. However, we want to tie our user's login with their logged-in status on Google: If they log out of Google, I want to log them out of our app.

Searching the net for solutions, I come up with the opposite question: how to sign users out of Google when they're done with our app? That's crazy.

Ideally, Google would provide a callback API that would inform my application when the user has logged out. I've also seen [another hacky solution](https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information) that allows you to determine if a user is logged into any Google account, but I'd prefer something a little more accurate (a specific vs any user).

I've also seen hints that Google's Contacts API could be used to determine status.

## **UPDATE**

I've continued to do some research on this in the past week, and I'll post my findings here. Looking at the Google Docs for the OAuth2 process, there appear to be two similar-yet-distinct setups:

1. [OAuth2 for Web Servers](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)
2. [OAuth2 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)

The Devise strategy gem that I'm employing for logging folks into my service appears to employ the first of these. However, the second technique uses the same endpoint and has almost all the same parameters, and the doc states that the first technique applies to this one as well.

However, one possibility that I uncovered is that the Login (the second) process has a "prompt" parameter which accepts a "none" value. When this is set, the docs say that the auth request will immediately return an error if the user is logged in already. Combined with the "login_hint" parameter where I can provide a user's email addres, and this would be the clear path to solving my problem.

BUT. Using the second technique, the authorization request always returns an immediate error regardless of whether I'm actually logged in or not. I wonder if it's got anything to do with the fact that I'm actually logging in via the first technique? To properly test this, I would have to gut my authentication system and replace it with this second technique.